# Alignment of Vaadin custom fields

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to create a delete button that fits nicely into a Vaadin form (and maybe in the future even more custom fields). I can't seem to get the alignment correctly. How should this be done properly?

See click me button in:

- https://vaadin-example-cknsvo.stackblitz.io
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vaadin-example-cknsvo?file=views/engatta-app.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap those elements with a flexbox, such as a `vaadin-horizontal-layout` or just a div with `display:flex` they will align vertically.

Comment: Strange thing is: when I do this the box only becomes smaller. Can you create a working example in a fork in the stackblitz?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but here's a fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vaadin-example-rjttrz?file=views/engatta-app.ts

Also noticed you need to reset the line-height on the button to 1 because custom-field messes with it. (CustomField is not really optimized for buttons)

Comment: Overall, wrapping things in CustomFields does not magically give you a nice form layout. You should consider using vaadin-form-layout or building something custom e.g. using flexbox.

Comment: the line height of the button was, the problem, thanks!